# Show that had a group of D&D style adventurers?

Tags: tv, story-identification

The TV show might have aired in the mid to late 90s or very early 2000s (no more than 2001). It was a classic medieval adventure show with a main character that was a young man, who wore classic warrior clothing (like what Hercules wore in Young Hercules). There was also a mage on the show that wore a cape with a hoodie that looked like an eagle (The mage might have been native American).

The intro had the characters walking up a mountain with tons of ice covered mountains in the background.

In one episode they are in a castle that they can not leave. There are two brothers there, one who can not lie and the other who always lies. The main character asks them how to leave and they show him two doors; one door will kill him and the other is they way out, and he can only ask the brothers one question. He figures out the riddle (but they never show the question he asked) and they all escape and then the castle disappears.

The show had the same filming style as the young Hercules show, might have been a Canadian show and they talked in the "ye olde style".
If any one can name the show I would be very grateful!!!!!

It was a live action show aimed at young teens and they also had a princess type character in the group (she eats a poison apple in the same episode).

Comment: This riddle is usually called "[Knights And Knaves](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/KnightsAndKnaves)" riddle

Comment: It was live action

Comment: It looks like you've accidentally split your account, you can go [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge) for instructions on re-combining them.

Comment: The 10th Kingdom had both poisoned-apple, and a knights/knaves scenario; but, nothing else seems to match.  [Here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RcKgcF-FU9M)'s the intro, anyhow.

Answer (score 15):

After looking at every fantasy show I could find, I finally found the answer to my own question (I have been looking for it for 4 years now!). It is a New Zealand show called *[The Legend Of William Tell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Legend_of_William_Tell)*. Sorry for wasting your time and, by the way, it is a very good show to watch. Thank you all!

> The Legend of William Tell is a 16-part television fantasy/drama series produced in 1998 by Cloud 9 Productions in New Zealand. The basic premise of the series — a crossbow-wielding rebel defies a corrupt governor — and the name of the title character were adopted from the traditional story, but the series was set in a fantasy world and featured supernatural themes.
>
> Described by executive producer Raymond Thompson as "Star Wars on the planet Earth", this is a fantasy saga of bravery, magic, myth and romance. William Tell is the youthful leader of a band of young, 'brat pack' outlaws, forever hunted by the forces of darkness, led by Xax and Kreel, who have usurped power in their homeland. The series of self-contained stories follows Will's quest to restore young Princess Vara to her rightful place on the royal throne and defeat Xax and Kreel's forces — and by doing so, bring back peace and order to the Kingdom of Kale.
>
> There is action and adventure along the way, magic, creatures, mystery, intrigue — but also much human drama and interplay among Will's rebel band who must support each other in their quest. The group encounter a diverse range of people and situations on their journey — some help the resistance movement, others are cohorts of Xax and Kreel.
>
> Filmed on location throughout New Zealand, the series makes use of natural scenery and has high production values.

Comment: It's perfectly fine to find the answer to your own question, no need to apologize

Comment: If you're still around or if you return, feel free to accept your own answer. :)

Comment: It's good that you found it, I was going to suggest the Conan TV show with Ralf Moeller :)